# root domain to www forwarding issue

Tags: domain-name-system, ping, forwarding

I want to forward my root domain(yourdomain.com) to www.yourdomain.com 
Should I delete the A record of the root domain and then setup 301 permanent forwarding to www.yourdomain.com?

I am hosting my app on heroku. So I don't really have an IP address to setup an A record.

The thing is I first deleted the A record of my root domain and then forwarded it.
I pinged it and here is the result -

```
ping yourdomain.com
ping: cannot resolve yourdomain.com: Unknown host
```

Update and some more information - 
 I am hosting a static website. And managing the DNS on cloudflare.com I added an A record for yourdomain.com -> 184.168.221.51 Just an random IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask you DNS provider whether they can set up a 301 HTTP redirect from yourdomain.com to www.yourdomain.com. Several DNS providers do this for free in their own webserver.

CloudFlare can solve HTTP redirect too: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172286-How-do-I-do-url-forwarding-with-CloudFlare-

Or you can use wildcard domains names:

```
* CNAME yourapp.heroku.com
```

Heroku has a quite good description about the different solutions: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Answer (score 2):

if you remove `A` record, then you won't be able to setup your 301 redirect, you should put it back and do 301 within your web server.

*** UPDATE ***

by pointing A record to "random IP" won't really solve anything, UNLESS you manage a web server on that random IP and can set 301 redirect there (which I'm sure you have no control over it) so solution is simple here, point A record to *RIGHT* IP address and then setup your 301 redirect.

Comment: I am hosting my app on heroku. So I don't really have an IP address to setup an A record.

Comment: @user182332 First, that's important information, and really something you should have told us in your question. [You should edit it your question to include that information.](http://serverfault.com/posts/546749/edit). Second, without some DNS entry for `yourdomain.com` you can't do *anything* on the web server level (like a 301 redirect). If you can't create an `A` record for that domain, you can't do what you want.

Comment: I just edited the question!
Some more information: I am hosting a static website. And managing the DNS on cloudflare.com
I added an A record for yourdomain.com -> 184.168.221.51
Just an random IP.